# Multiple Radio Button are getting Selected while Using with <apex:repeat>

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I am trying to create Radio Button using `<apex:repeat>` and in `{!recordList}` i have 7 records so it will create 7 Radio Buttons. But the problem is that all 7 Buttons are getting Selected and i want only one at a time.
Someone told me that you can use `<apex:repeat>` after `<apex:selectRadio` so radio list will be one 1 and have 7 options but in that case what will be the value of `<apex:selectRadio>`because i need this Id to perform some functioning

VF Page

```
<apex:repeat value="{!recordList}" var="rep">
    <apex:selectRadio id="isRadio" value="{!rep.isSelected}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
    </apex:selectRadio>
</apex:repeat>
```

Controller

```
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('true',''));
        return options;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each apex:radioGroup is a unique record group. You can select all of them because they separate radio groups. In other words, you're expecting code like the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" />
...
```

But what you're really getting is:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" />
<input type="radio" name="group2" />
...
```

This allows all of them to be selected.

---

If you need just one group, you need to use some JavaScript. That said, the JS you need is only used to associate the inputs to a bound input value:

```
    <script>
    function updateHidden(event) {
        document.querySelector("[id$=selectedValue]").value = event.target.value;
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
    </script>
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!selectedValue}" id="selectedValue" />
    <apex:repeat value="{!recordList}" var="rep">
        <input name="isRadio" type="radio" onchange="updateHidden(event)" value="{!rep.value}" label="{!rep.value}" />
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:form>
```

This should give you the functionality you need with various non-standard layouts.

Comment: Here in ```<apex:inputHidden value="{!selectedValue}"``` what is ```selectedValue```. Where it is defined as i can not directly access this in VF

Comment: @ManishKumar Specify the variable in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use Input Tag for Radio Button as shown below

```
<td>
  <input name="isRadio" type="radio" value="{!rep.Id}" /><br/>
</td>
```

[Click here to see Implementation of Radio Button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274052/facing-problem-in-single-select-radio-button/274094?noredirect=1#comment413598_274094)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a javascript function to make sure only one radio button is selected at a time. This works for checkboxes, I haven't tried it with radio buttons

```
function deselectOtherBoxes(selectedBox){

        if(selectedBox.checked){

            var allBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');

            for (let i = 0; i < allBoxes.length; i++) {

                if (allBoxes[i].checked) {
                    allBoxes[i].checked = false;
                }        
            }
            selectedBox.checked = true;
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it this way

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Select</apex:facet>
     <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!con.selected}" onchange="deselectOtherBoxes(this)"/>
 </apex:column>
```

Comment: Thanks @CommomCoreTawan but,  it will not work because the problem is here that i am using ```<apex:repeat>``` and this is creating multiple ```<apex:selectRadio>``` elements each with a single ```<apex:selectOption/> ```element, which is basically creating multiple groups of one radio button.